# command substitution within single quotes for alias

Tags: bash, alias, command-substitution

Double quotes are required in bash for command substitution:

```
$ echo "$(date)"
Fri Oct 28 19:16:40 EDT 2016
```

Whereas single quotes do not do command substitution:

```
$ echo '$(date)'
$(date)
```

… why then do I see the following behavior with `alias` that seems to suggest that command substitution happened with single quotes?

```
alias d='$(date)'
$ d
No command 'Fri' found, did you mean:
   ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Single-quote vs double-quote versions

Let's define the alias using single-quotes:

```
$ alias d='$(date)'
```

Now, let's retrieve the definition of the alias:

```
$ alias d
alias d='$(date)'
```

Observe that no command substitution was yet performed.

Let's do the same, but this time with double-quotes:

```
$ alias d="$(date)"
$ alias d
alias d='Fri Oct 28 17:01:12 PDT 2016'
```

Because double-quotes are used, command substitution was performed before the alias was defined.

#### Single-quote version

Let's try executing the single-quote version:

```
$ alias d='$(date)'
$ d
bash: Fri: command not found
```

The single-quote version is equivalent to running:

```
$ $(date)
bash: Fri: command not found
```

In both cases, the command substitution is performed when the command is executed.

#### A variation

Let's consider this alias which uses command substitution and is defined using single-quotes:

```
$ alias e='echo $(date)'
$ e
Fri Oct 28 17:05:29 PDT 2016
$ e
Fri Oct 28 17:05:35 PDT 2016
```

Every time that we run this command, `date` is evaluated again.  With single-quotes, the command substitution is performed when the alias is executed, not when it is defined.

Answer (score 5):

If you use double quotes when defining an alias, the parameter expansion occurs at the *alias definition* time.

For example:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ echo $PWD
/tmp
$ alias p="echo $PWD"
$ p
/tmp
$ cd /
$ pwd
/
$ p
/tmp
$ alias p
alias p='echo /tmp'
$
```

If you want the parameter expansion to occur at the time you *call* the alias, use single quotes when defining the alias:

```
$ alias p='echo $PWD'
$ p
/tmp
$ cd /
$ p
/
$
```

Of course there is never *any* reason to run the command <s>`echo "$(date)"`</s>.  I know you used this just as an example, but since I have seen this so many times "in the wild" I'll clarify anyway: What this means is, run the `date` command and capture the output (stripping off any trailing newlines).  Then pass that captured output as an argument to the `echo` command, which will print it, along with a single trailing newline.  There is no advantage at all over just running `date` directly.

However, you are having a different problem here as well:

When you set the alias `d='$(date)'`, when you type `d` you will get the literal result of typing `$(date)` at the command line—the `date` command will be executed, the output captured, the trailing newline will be stripped, and then the output will be parsed as a command by the shell (including word splitting and file glob expansion).

Since it's Friday, the first word output by `date` is "Fri", so the shell tries to run this as a command.

If what you want is to *see* the date when you type `d`, just use:

```
alias d=date
```

or

```
alias d='date'
```

or

```
alias d="date"
```

It doesn't matter which form you use, as there are no special characters requiring any form of quoting.

Comment: This was an example to motivate the question only, specifically to show that `alias` treated the command substitution differently than `echo`, not meant to be real code. I upvoted but I suggest that you drop the part of your answer explaining why it's not a good idea to run `echo "$(date)"`

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, fair enough.  :)  I've seen that exact style of code so many times (in actual production scripts!) that I'm leaving the explanation in, but I toned it down a bit.

Comment: `alias` *doesn't* treat the command substitution differently. But alias *expansion* occurs before command substitution during the shell's evaluation process; the shell doesn't consider whether `$(date)` was produced by typing or alias expansion when deciding what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it going about `~/.bashrc`? There is a commented part in the `~/.bashrc`

```
    95 # Alias definitions.                                              
    96 # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
    97 # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.          
    98 # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
```

and that's why I use another, suggested file for my shortcuts:

the `~/.bash_aliases`

The key is to escape the single quote:

```
# I use vim but nano or gedit is also fine
vim ~/.bashrc # or vim ~/.bash_aliases
# create your alias:
alias d=''\'date''\'
# or
alias dd="'date'"
# or
alias ddd='"date"'
```

Then open a new terminal session and `d` will execute what you want.